# How to solve a nonlinear system of equations with exponential terms

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to solve this parametric nonlinear system of equations in Mathematica:

$$x−1−(e^{a−x}+e^{b−y})/(c+e^{b−y})=0$$

$$y−1−(e^{b−y})/(c+e^{a−x})=0$$

and I used this code:

```
Solve[{x - 1 - (Exp[a - x] + Exp[b - y])/(c + Exp[b - y]) == 0, y - 1 - (Exp[b - y])/(c + Exp[a - x]) == 0}, {x, y}]
```

but I got this message: *This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve*

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: It just cannot be solved by `Solve` - it's too difficult. If a,b are known values please provide the numbers - in which case you could try `NSolve` for a numerical solution, otherwise if you need a symbolic solution in $a,b,c$ I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: `but I got this message:` how long did it take you to get this message?  its been running for 20 minutes on my 12.31. You should really mention the version number and the OS also.

Comment: Not clear what is meant by "what's the problem". The result (unevaluated) and the message make pretty clear what has happened. What different outcome would you propose?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Everyone expects that the powerful Mathematica should be able to solve any equation, ode, pde, integral, or any math problem. It does not matter if there exists a solution or not  :)

Comment: @Nasser: Why do you think the solutions of the system under consideration can be expressed in a closed form? Please ground your  above claim. TIA.

Comment: Nasser did not claim that a closed form for this system exists.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this can be done only numerically after evaluating the parameters `a,b,c`, for example, in such a way. We extract the LHSes of the equations by `[[1]]`, square these by `Map[#^2 &,...]`,  sum the squares by `Total`, and evaluate the parameters by `/. {a -> 1, b -> -2, c -> 3}`. Then we apply `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[Total[Map[#^2 &, {(x - 
     1 - (Exp[a - x] + Exp[b - y])/(c + Exp[b - y]) == 
    0)[[1]], (y - 1 - (Exp[b - y])/(c + Exp[a - x]) == 
    0)[[1]]}]] /. {a -> 1, b -> -2, c -> 3}, {x, y}]
```

> `{0., {x -> 1.26718, y -> 1.01305}}`

If you are interested in the solutions over the complexes, then that approach should be modified.

Comment: The results of the commands of Maple `plots:-implicitplot([-1 - (exp(1 - x) + exp(-2 - y))/(3 + exp(-2 - y)) + x = 0, -1 - exp(-2 - y)/(3 + exp(1 - x)) + y = 0], x = -5 .. 5, y = -5 .. 5, color = [blue, red])`  and `fsolve([-1 - (exp(1 - x) + exp(-2 - y))/(3 + exp(-2 - y)) + x = 0, -1 - exp(-2 - y)/(3 + exp(1 - x)) + y = 0])`confirm my answer ( see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4ypmiogdt1byhj/root.pdf?dl=0))

Answer (score 1):

You can get solutions in terms of `Root` expressions for defined a,b,c.

Use the fact that f^2+g^2 has a minimum at intersection point to get additional equations.

You get two separated transzendental equations for x and y.

```
{f, g} = {x - 1 - (Exp[a - x] + Exp[b - y])/(c + Exp[b - y]), 
          y - 1 - (Exp[b - y])/(c + Exp[a - x])}

ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[{f == 0, g == 0} /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}], {x, 0, 
    4}, {y, 0, 4}]

FindRoot[{f == 0, g == 0} /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, {x, 2}, {y, 2}]

(*   {x -> 1.69589, y -> 1.43284}   *)

Plot3D[{0, f^2 + g^2 /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 
  4}]

df = D[f^2 + g^2, x] // Together // Numerator // Simplify

dg = D[f^2 + g^2, y] // Together // Numerator // Simplify

elix = Eliminate[{f == 0, df == 0, g == 0, dg == 0}, x]

(*   Log[-((E^b + c E^y - c E^y y)/(1 - y))] == -1 + a - E^b/(
E^b + c E^y) + y + (
E^b + c E^y - c E^y y)/((E^b + c E^y) (1 - y)) && E^b + c E^y != 0   *)

Solve[elix[[1]] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, y, Reals]

(*   {{y -> Root[{-E^#1 - 2 E #1 + E #1^2 + E^#1 #1^2 + 
   Log[-((E + E^#1 - E^#1 #1)/(1 - #1))] (E + E^#1 (1 - #1) - 
      E #1) &, 1.43283890934916955086}]}}   *)

eliy = Eliminate[{f == 0, df == 0, g == 0, dg == 0}, y]

Solve[eliy[[1]] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, x, Reals]

(*   {{x -> Root[{-E - E^#1 - 2 E #1 - E^#1 #1 + E #1^2 + E^#1 #1^2 + 
   Log[-((E + E^#1 - E^#1 #1)/(2 - #1))] (2 E + E^#1 (2 - #1) - 
      E #1) &, 1.69589278283101356668}]}}   *)
```

Comment: In fact, `Solve[eliy[[1]] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, x, Reals]
` and 
`Solve[elix[[1]] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, y, Reals]` are  numerical solutions camouflaged  by `Root[..]`. Before solving, the parameters are evaluated.

Comment: Yes, that's true and clear. But sometimes root expressions, instead of pure numbers, are of advantage for further algebraic calculations.

Comment: Akku (@ does not work.): Can you give such an example, grounding your  words? TIA.